# How to prevent warnings like No xauth data when doing ssh from OS X to other machines?

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh, xserve

I get `Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.` when I do ssh to other machines from my OS X machine which has X-server installed.

`echo $DISPLAY` returns something like `/tmp/launch-4eEyr6/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`

Inside `~/.ssh/config` I specified `XAuthLocation xauth` but I still get the errors.

If I replace the line with full path to xauth (`/opt/X11/bin/xauth`), I stop getting the errors but the problem is that I do share the ssh config file between several machines, so I cannot put a path that is specific to Mac on it.

I would prefer a solution that would not require me to create a symlink on Mac from `/opt/X11/bin/xauth` to `/usr/bin/xauth`.

Answer (score 5):

Put `XAuthLocation=/opt/X11/bin/xauth` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Answer (score 4):

I see it's an old question but for the sake of Google, here is my answer.

On the Mac, you can create an alias in ~/.bashrc like so:

```
alias ssh='ssh -o "XAuthLocation=/opt/X11/bin/xauth"'
```

If you also share the .bashrc across both OS X and other unixy machines, you could add a little stanza to the .bashrc as follows:

```
if [ `uname` == 'Darwin' ]; then
    alias ssh='ssh -o "XAuthLocation=/opt/X11/bin/xauth"'
fi
```

Comment: I'd like to add that you can edit the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file on the individual machines to add the XAuthLocation information that applies to that particular machine.